# returning DB data via ajax json

Tags: ajax, json, database, laravel

I am posting data to a controller via ajax (selected) and want to return some database json-data. When I just return the sent data (selected) it works all fine but as soon as I want to return DB data I receive a server 500 error (Eloquent Model certainly exists and works on another function in same class). Thanks for any hints!

Ajax Call:

```
$('#country').on('change', function(){
var selected = $('#country').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "inputChange",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {selected: selected},
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data.name_en);
});
});
```

Route:

```
Route::any('inputChange', array(
    'as' => 'inputChange',
    'uses' => 'UserController@inputChange'
));
```

Controller (working fine without DB data):

```
public function inputChange(){
    $selected = Input::get('selected');
    return Response::json($selected);
}
```

Controller (not working with DB data - error 500 - below is without the where clause for $selected):

```
public function inputChange(){
    $selected = Input::get('selected');
    $data = City::all()->get();
    return Response::json($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `get()` the City data when doing `all()`. So your code should be:

```
public function inputChange(){
    $selected = Input::get('selected');
    $data = City::all();
    return Response::json($data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! The 500 error is still present also without get()

Comment: Ok, then look at your log file to see what it says and post the error details. You can do `php artisan tail` to monitor your log file.